# How to use underscore.js with webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, visual-studio-code, aurelia

I would like to use underscore in my Typescript Aurelia application.
I created a typescript file where i put:

```
import * as _ from 'underscore'
```

but VS Code says:

> [ts] Cannot find module 'underscore'

I have put this into webpack.config:

```
plugins:[
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      underscore:'underscore'
    })  
]
```

Also i have installed underscore using:

```
npm install --save underscore
```

what else must I do to get it to work?

Comment: There is a typo here: `npm install --save undersocre`. Did you copy/paste? or you made the typo only writing here?

Comment: Typo when i wrote the line here.

Comment: You shouldn't need the provideplugin since you've installed it with npm. webpack will automatically bundle underscore into your main javascript bundle and your javascript files will run fine. however that shouldn't affect typescript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are working with TypeScript, you must also install a `*.d.ts` typings file for underscore. Try running:

```
npm install --save @types/underscore
```

This  lets TS know about the underscore module and its interfaces.

[Here's some more information about typings management with Typescript](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/)